# How can I fix my pagination?

Tags: php, functions, theme-development

I'm trying to get pagination working on my custom wp_query post loop. I currently have it set up, but when I click on page 2, it shows the exact same posts from page 1. I have a total of about 8 posts and the limit set to 5 posts per page. Below you can see the function found in my functions.php file

```
if ( !function_exists( 'wpex_pagination' ) ) {

function wpex_pagination() {

$prev_arrow = is_rtl() ? '&rarr;' : '&larr;';
$next_arrow = is_rtl() ? '&larr;' : '&rarr;';

global $wp_query,$the_query;

if ( $the_query ) {
  $total = $the_query->max_num_pages;
  } else {
  $total = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
  }
  $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
    if( $total > 1 )  {
         if( !$current_page = get_query_var('paged') )
             $current_page = 1;
         if( get_option('permalink_structure') ) {
             $format = 'page/%#%/';
         } else {
             $format = '&paged=%#%';
         }
        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base'          => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'format'        => $format,
            'current'       => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
            'total'         => $total,
            'mid_size'      => 3,
            'type'          => 'list',
            'prev_text'     => $prev_arrow,
            'next_text'     => $next_arrow,
      ) );
    }
  }
}
```

and then below is the loop on my template page page-news.php

```
<?php
        $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=5' );
        if ($the_query -> have_posts()) :
        while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post();
      ?>

      <div class="row blog-excerpts">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="angled-img">
            <div class="img">
              <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="clearfix">
            <h3 class="h2 pull-left">
              <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </h3>
            <span class="date pull-right">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
              <?php the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ); ?>
            </span>
          </div>

          <div class="description">
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
          </div>

          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn">Read More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); wpex_pagination(); endif;  ?>
```

any help or pointers in to the right direction is very much appreciated. I've been trying to get this working for a few days now and have read over numerous articles on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the ***paged*** parameter to your WPQuery:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'paged' => $paged ) );
```

Here are the [docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters).

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it was that simple. For some reason I thought that paged was something already set by default so I didn't need to set it. Really glad you got that cleared up for me, it was getting pretty frustrating.